# Sonar configuration for Java + Javascript project

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have a project with java (backend) and javascript parts (frontend).

I need to configure Sonar to get test results and coverage report.

For **Java** I have tests:

- Junit
- REST-assured

Used maven plugins for test report and coverage: `JoCoCo`, `Surefire`, `Failsave`

For **JS** part I have:

- Angular Unit test
- UI test

To run tests and get reports was used:

- Runners: `Karma` and `Protractor`
- Task manager: `Grunt`

So I need:

```
 to get reports from:

 #1 - Java Unit tests
 #2 - Java Integration Tests
 #3 - JS Unit tests
 #4 - JS UI tests
```

As it multilingual project I have to use `sonar runner` , instead of `mvn sonar:sonar`.

** How can I setup sonar-project.properties for the project? **

I found some useful link, but still cannot get how to create common project:

- [Pre-configured projects](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the following sample project to get inspired: https://github.com/bellingard/multi-language-test